# VBScript create and open a new file

Tags: vbscript

I try to make a script in VBScript for PowerAMC.
And I've got an error.

I checked all elements to make a file with the content (XSD file):

```
private Sub writeInFile(pathFolder, pathFile, val)
  Output "WriteInFile["&pathFolder&pathFile&"]"
  Dim fso, MyFile
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile(pathFolder&pathFile, true)
  If (fso.FileExists(pathFolder&pathFile)) Then
    MyFile.WriteLine(val)
  Else
    ouput "File can't be create"
  End If

  MyFile.Close
  end Sub
```

And the file exists with good content, but if I try to read it with:

```
public Function readFile(path)
  'Declare variables
  Dim objFSO, objReadFile, contents

  'Set Objects
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path, 1, false)

  'Read file contents
  contents = objReadFile.ReadAll

  'Close file
  objReadFile.close

  'Cleanup objects
  Set objFSO = Nothing
  Set objReadFile = Nothing

  readFile = contents
   End Function
```

I get that : "ÿþ<" for only content, but if I try to read a file that is not created by the previous function, it runs perfectly.

Comment: You're probably trying to read an UTF-8 encoded file. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13855268/4584335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from Unicode format,
take a look at this => [FileSystemObject - Reading Unicode Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410334/filesystemobject-reading-unicode-files)

Comment: I had solved the problem with : 
Set oReadfile = FS.OpenTextFile(sFile, 1, False, True) The true argument fixed the bug,  THX !